# Variable contains data but it is not printed out

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am fetching data from database and trying to display it in a view but it does not work. However, `print_r` outputs the data successfully.

Model:

```
<?php
class Usermodel Extends CI_model{
    public function getUserdata() 
    {
        $this->load->database();
        // $q=$this->db->select('name');
        $q=$this->db->get('user');
        return $q->result_array();
    }
}
?>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Users extends CI_controller{
    public function User(){
        $this->load->model('Usermodel');
        $data['users']=$this->Usermodel->getUserdata();
        $this->load->view('Users/userlist',$data);

    }
}
?>
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>User Details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <?php print_r($users); ?>
    <h1>User Account Details</h1>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Account No</td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($users as $users): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php $users['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php $users['accountnumber']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of `foreach($users as $users)` use `foreach($users as $user)`. You're overwriting the `$users` variable.

Comment: You don't print anything within that loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use either `echo` construct or short echo tag in your view. Short echo tag is more preferred as it is more concise. For example: `<?= $users['name'] ?>`

In your code you just return the value of variables to nowhere instead of printing it out so the result is not showing.

Comment: It's working it this implementation

Answer (score 0):

You should use `echo` .

For your code example write `<td><?php echo $users['name']; ?></td>`

Comment: ok i will already use